# Complexity of the Automorphism problem in group with polynomial growth.

Tags: group-theory, computational-complexity

Do we have any characterization of groups with a decidable automorphism problem ? 
When it is decidable, Is there any results about the complexity of the automorphism problem in group with polynomial growth ? 
In the case of nilpotent group the word problem is known to be polynomial ... do we have any clue for the automorphism problem ? 
Does there exists groups with polynomial growth and undecidable automorphim problem ?

Thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

By Gromov's result, a group with polynomial growth is virtually nilpotent, and hence virtually polycyclic. Segal proved that virtually polycyclic groups have solvable automorphism group and isomorphism problems. But I am not aware of any efficient algorithms. It is a difficult problem even for finite $p$-groups.

Comment: Thanks for this incredible fast answer! Well it is interesting. In the case of polynomial growth and polynomial time word problem, are you aware of any results ? Thanks